# shared_ptr with map (error error C2664)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a class with a shared_ptr data member. Below is an example

```
class A {
private:
    shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> _pMap;
    A();
public:
    A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>>); 
    A(const A& source);
    A& operator=A(const A&);
};

A::A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> mapPtr) 
: _pMap(new std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, std::string>>()) {
    _pMap = mapPtr;

A::A(const A& source) : _pMap(source._p) {}

A& A::operator=(const A& source) {
    if (this == &source) {
        return *this;
    }

    _pMap = source._pMap;

    return *this;
}
```

When I tried to compile my program with just the header included in the main program, I receive the following error:

```
error C2664: 'std::_Ptr_base<_Ty>::_Reset0' : 
             cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> *' 
             to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> *
```

But I am not sure where I am doing this. Can please someone guide as to why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: `But I am not sure where I am doing this` And neither do we if you don't post a *complete* but minimal example that duplicates the error. However, why are you writing a user-defined assignment operator and copy ctor? The default ones are perfectly fine for your class.

Comment: I think the problem could be the `A(const A& source);` and `A& operator=(const A& source)`. You'll need move constructor and assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem (or at least one of) is in the line

```
A::A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> mapPtr) : _pMap(new std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, std::string>>()) {
        _pMap = mapPtr;
```

it should be

```
A::A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> mapPtr) : _pMap(new std::map<int, std::string>()) {
        _pMap = mapPtr;
```

But there is not point to initialise _pMap twice - so for this constructor the best would be to do

```
A::A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> mapPtr) : _pMap(mapPtr) { }
```

Comment: Note that there is no point to that initialization anyway. It should be `_pMap(mapPtr)`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed part of your code:

```
class A 
{
private:
    shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> _pMap;
    A();
public:
    A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>>);
    A(const A& source);
};

A::A(shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> mapPtr)
{
    _pMap = mapPtr;
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<map<int, std::string>> myMap = std::make_shared<map<int, std::string>>
    ();
    A a(myMap);
    return 0;
}
```